# Remove the underline effect from mat-form-field input

Tags: angular, input, angular-material

I have an `input` using `Angular Material 14` and I get an underline by default when I click on the input. How can I remove this `underline`?

```
  <div class="filter-search">
     <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="filter-search-item">
        <input type="search" matInput />
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-icon matPrefix class="my-icon">search</mat-icon>
  </div>
```

I have tried to use appearance="none" but it gives error `Type '"none"' is not assignable to type 'MatFormFieldAppearance'.` 
Also using css I have used `::ng-deep` but it doesn't work either. And looking in the browser's inspector this way it should work, since it is how it appears, but it doesn't work either.

```
.filter-search-item .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-underline {
  height: 0px !important;
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Inspect element and get the class name and overwrite that class with you custom class, any stackblitz example would help if you can produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

This is expected because the only two possible appearance styles for the type [`MatFormFieldAppearance`](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormFieldAppearance) are `fill` and `outline`.

[image: Screenshot]

If you write the following code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="none">
  <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
  <input matInput />
</mat-form-field>
```

You'll get the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type '"none"' is not assignable to type 'MatFormFieldAppearance'.
```

Why do you get this error? If you look at `tsconfig.json`, you'll see that `strictTemplates` is set to `true` by default.

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true /* <-- This causes the error */
  }
}
```

#### Solution

Add the following CSS to your component CSS:

**form-field-overview-example.css**

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```

See the [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/o3ttqy-h5hg8v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-overview-example.css).

*Note: The code above will affect **all** `mat-form-field` elements inside this component. If you want to target only specific `mat-form-field` elements inside this component, you need to add a custom class.*

**form-field-overview-example.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="custom-class">
  <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
  <input matInput />
</mat-form-field>
```

**form-field-overview-example.css**

```
::ng-deep .custom-class .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```